# How to get rid of long scrolls on RecyclerView

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

This question might seem common to you, But I didn't find any compelling answer, So I brig it up and hope you can help.

If we have a large number of items to show in a `RecyclerView`, And by large I mean really large like **thousands** (but not at the same time), Scrolling from first item to the other items will be a real pain because of many items we have to navigate.

**Possible Solution:** At first look maybe breaking items to smaller parts and use of a `SeekBar` or a group of `Buttons` (*like page number buttons on stackoverflow questions page*) in order to choose each part(page) to review seems like a not bad idea.

**Question:** I'm curious is there any better and clean way to achieve this? Did android predict any tools or solution for this type of issues or it's up to developer like the solution I mentioned before?

Any advice means a lot to me and I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called pagination. Do not query for the entire 1000 records, query for first 20 and when recyclerView is scrolled to the bottom, query for next 20. It is standard way (in list or gridview too)

You must modify your service endpoints or database query to support this.

Comment: Thanks for response, Actually I'm feeding the adapter 30 items in every query not the whole items, I'm looking for a way to prevent adding next query results at the end of RecyclerView in order to keep items count fixed and turn pages so that the user don't have to navigate all the items, Do you know what I meant?

Comment: then have two buttons at header and footer called load previous and load next respectively. On click of these buttons do your show next or prev 30 items. Hide the buttons if needed.

Comment: So it's as I thought, I should handle it myself, Thanks again +1